# Dequeue answer from old Review List

Tags: support, review

I'm looking at answers in these lists on /review:

[image: screenshot of bottom of /review]

Is there any way that I, with my reputation (<110), can dequeue the answer from the Late Answers list, or, put them in a queue that will bring them closer to being dequeued.

I ask because I was trying to decide between commenting on an answer, or editing it to include the information that I was going to use in my comment. Between editing and commenting, I'd choose the option that actually does something to further the process of eliminating the /review list.

However, if neither of these things helps to process the Late Answers list, then maybe something needs to be rethought in terms of how the system operates, because it seems odd that I'm a) reviewing the answer, b) providing information to improve it, but c) not factoring into the reduction of the overall workload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have the Strunk & White badge yet, **nothing you do will further it being removed from the queue**. The *only* thing that will remove it from the queue is two users (who have the badge) clicking the "review this answer" button to expand it. No further action past that is even required as not everything actually needs something done to it.

Keep in mind also that these are the old review panels, which will eventually be removed and replaced with the new review tasks. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe clicking anything besides "Not Sure" in the new system will trigger its review count and move it along in getting it out of the queue (including the "Looks Good" option).

Comment: Will this new system, and all of its functionality, be open to those without the S&W badge? A subset of its functionality?

Comment: I haven't heard any mention of the badge being required in order for it to count as "reviewed" in the new system. As far as I'm aware, each task just has a minimum reputation requirement.